# While using tqdm as loading bar with tqdm.write("...something...", end="\r") there is no output to the console

Tags: python, printing, progress-bar, tqdm

I am writing a training loop and I want to print the loss on each step to the console and keep updating it throughout the training. How can I get the line to show up on the console and keep updating on each step while the tqdm bar is held in one place.

The loop I am using looks like this -

```
for epoch in range(start_epoch, end_epoch):
        print("="*70)
        print("EPOCH: [%d/%d]" % (epoch, end_epoch))
        print("="*70)
        for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader), 0):
            # Some Calculations and stuff

            # The Line to print and update throughout training
            tqdm.write("Loss: [%0.5f], MinLoss: [%0.5f]" % (losses[-1],min_loss), end = "\r")
          
            # Some Other Stuff
                
        print("Loss:" , [round(i,5) for i in losses[-10:]])
        print("MinLoss:", round(min_loss,5))
```

Is there something that I am missing? Is there any other way to do this?

ps. I have also tried using print function and i am able to glimpse the line on the console but the bar keeps duplicating itself after each print [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1IXt.png)